# Best way to iterate through entries delimited by two keywords?

Tags: python, string

Text File contents:

```
&CRB  A='test1'   B=123,345, 678   &END
Misc text potentially between entries ...
&CRB  A='test2'   
             B=788, 345, 3424   &END
&CRB  A='test3'   
             B=788, 345, 3424   &END
&CRB  A='test4' B=788, 345, 3424   &END
```

What is the most efficient way to iterate through the entries between the keywords? Note 
that some entries span lines. Something like the following is desired -

```
f = open(filename)
for entry in f:
    - do something with entry
```

Of course it is not that easy. But, are there suggestions on a straightforward way to iterate thorough the entries delimiated by two key words.

Comment: What is an entry? `A='test1'   B=123,345, 678`, `A='test1'` or `123`?

Comment: How big is the file?  All of the posters are assuming that it would be read into memory and parsed there.  Which is probably good assumption for 99% of practical examples?  But if not, you would probably need to read it line by line and assemble entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the entry is all of the text between `&CRB` and `&END` pairs, you can pull out the text between them with something like this:

```
import re

# the regular expression treats newlines as a regular character, so the
# multiline entries are okay. It's non-greedy, so it gets individual entries.
pat = re.compile(r'&CRB(.+?)&END',  re.DOTALL)

s = ''' &CRB  A='test1'   B=123,345, 678   &END
Misc text potentially between entries ...
&CRB  A='test2'   
             B=788, 345, 3424   &END
&CRB  A='test3'   
             B=788, 345, 3424   &END
&CRB  A='test4' B=788, 345, 3424   &END'''

for entry in pat.findall(s):
   # do something with each entry
   print entry
```

prints this:

```
 A='test1'   B=123,345, 678   
  A='test2'   
             B=788, 345, 3424   
  A='test3'   
             B=788, 345, 3424   
  A='test4' B=788, 345, 3424
```

...it's your problem to clean up and interpret the contents of each of those records...

Comment: `[line.strip('&CRB').strip('&END').strip() for line in open('file')]`. There is no need of `re`. The main issue is that of cleanup :)

Comment: @sukhbir -- not true if entries can span across lines as the OP specified.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it is what I needed. Followup up question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248010/how-to-exclude-comment-lines-when-searching-with-regular-expression

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.finditer) instead of [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.findall), since we do not know the size of the file parsing it in one time might be too much ram-consuming, while having an iterator yielding the results will prevent the program from eating too much RAM.

So I think the best solution is [the one posted by bgporter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4233328/510937), using pat.finditer instead of pat.findall in the for loop.
finditer yields `MatchObject`s and not strings, to obtain the string matched just call `.group()`:

```
for entry in pat.finditer(s):
    entry_text = entry.group()
    #do something with entry_text.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would read in the file, use filecontents.split('&CRB') and then parse each line with regular expressions (see `re` module).