# How to exclude comment lines when searching with regular expression?

Tags: python, string

Need to exclude blocks that are located with a regular expression when preceded with # and any number of spaces. Here is a example file

```
&START   A=23  ... more data ...
                  B=24    &END
#   &START   A=34  ... more data ...
                  B=24    &END
&START   .... block 3 of data across multiple lines ....  &END
&START   .... block 4 of data across multiple lines ....  &END
```

The following regular expression does not exclude the commented entry as I expected -

```
(?!#\s*)&START(.+?)&END
```

The desire is to walk through the entries and the file for processing. Python code to do this (which works well other than comment lines making it through) -

```
f=open(filename)
data=f.read()
f.close()

pattern=re.compiler(r'(?!#\s*)&START(.+?)&END, re.DOTALL)
get_entries = pattern.findall

for entry in get_entries(data):
    # process the entry
    print entry
```

Likely a basic oversight as I am green when it comes to regular expressions. Many thanks for anyone who can make a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
import re

target="""
&START   A=23  ... more data ...
                  B=24    &END
#   &START   A=C34  ... more data ...
                  B=C24    &END
&START   .... block 3 of data across multiple lines ....  &END
&START   .... block 4 of data across multiple lines ....  &END
"""

regex = re.compile("^(?!#)&START (.*?)&END",re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

for s in regex.findall(target):
   print s
```

Returns:

```
  A=23  ... more data ...
                  B=24    
  .... block 3 of data across multiple lines ....  
  .... block 4 of data across multiple lines ....
```

Comment: This works. Slight cleanup of expression to capture the essential elements:

Comment: regx=re.compile("\n[^#]*?&START(.+?)&END", re.DOTALL)

Answer (score 6):

Skip the line altogether.

```
if line.lstrip().startswith('#'):
  continue
```

Comment: Thanks for the response; but, the search is across multiple lines. In other words, the entry between &START and &END may span multiple lines.

Comment: @tnt: give us a better set of possibilities so the answers would help more.

Comment: @tnt: So then use a state machine.

Comment: @tnt: How can a legal Python comment starting with a hash span multiple lines?

Comment: Thanks for the questions - I have editted the questions with hopes of better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

This is best worked into a generator.
Using the (m) multiline tag will allow it to search the next line till it finds your end tag.